# Кто может объяснить

Tags: reactjs

```
export default class PersonDetails extends Component {

  swapiService = new SwapiService();

  state = {
    person: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updatePerson();
  }

  updatePerson() {
    const { personId } = this.props;
    if (!personId) {
      return;
    }

    this.swapiService
      .getPerson(2)
      .then((person) => {
        this.setState({ person });
      });
  }

  render() {

    /*if (!this.state.person) {
      return <span>Select a person from a list</span>;
    }*/
    const { name, gender,
              birthYear, eyeColor } = this.state.person;

    return (
      <div className="person-details card">
        <img className="person-image"
          //src={`https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/characters/${id}.jpg`}
          alt="character"/>

        <div className="card-body">
          <h4>{name} {this.props.personId}</h4>
          <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li className="list-group-item">
              <span className="term">Gender</span>
              <span>{gender}</span>
            </li>
            <li className="list-group-item">
              <span className="term">Birth Year</span>
              <span>{birthYear}</span>
            </li>
            <li className="list-group-item">
              <span className="term">Eye Color</span>
              <span>{eyeColor}</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Почему, если я убираю условие в `render`, то код не работает?

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Ничего не выводится? Ошибка?

Comment: Выведите в консоль то, что ваш `swapiService` возвращает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

udalmik прав, но немного добавлю для ясности

1.

```
state = {
    person: null   };
```

2. Данная операция скорее всего асинхронный запрос куда то...

   this.swapiService
         .getPerson(2)
         .then((person) => {
           this.setState({ person });
3. и в рендере Вы делаете

   const { name, gender,
                 birthYear, eyeColor } = this.state.person;

Без условия у Вас 3 пункт выполняется сразу после 1 . Вы из null пытаетесь достать данные

Answer (score 0):

Не указано что за ошибка, но неожиданное поведение может быть связано с тем что

```
this.swapiService
      .getPerson(2)
```

это асинхронная операция, результат придет позже а выполнение сразу выйдет из `componentDidMount`, далее React вызовет `render` на пустом person в state => ошибка.